Teens animated racing show
I remember this show that was about cars literally racing underground and they were like a gang of racers fighting for rights or something. The show was 2d animated with a dark tone to it. I also remember flying drones that had to be shot down and portals that closed if they didn't escape in time. it may have been from like 2010 or something and it was NOT a hot wheels show.

Could that be Motorcity ?
Plot snippet:

... band of hot-rod wielding rebels fights to protect Motorcity - the
  last oasis of freedom - from the power-hungry Kane and his endless
  army of technological terrors. Motorcity is a high-octane animated
  action-comedy that celebrates freedom and independence with cool cars,
  great action, and dynamic heroes who stand up for what they believe
  in.

